# JOSSO 1.8 in Play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, josso

How do I use JOSSO to authenticate users to a Play 2 application?

I can't even find information on how to use the JOSSO agent outside of a Java EE container. Surely someone must have done this before?

Comment: can you help me do some configuration in JOSSO2.4. i'm there http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78071/josso2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [josso-microsoft-agent](https://github.com/atricore/josso1/tree/master/agents/josso-microsoft-agent) as an example. The class [JOSSOActiveX](https://github.com/atricore/josso1/blob/master/agents/josso-microsoft-agent/src/main/java/org/josso/activex/JOSSOActiveX.java) could be used for redirect to login, validate assertions, and register session access. See example of usage in *.asp files.

So you have to:

- create play annotation to manage requests authorization
- manage cookies from play when a session exists
- check ASSERTION_ID when session not exists

This is the theory. I hope you are interested and help someone.